# rake assets:precompile does not work compiling locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

I just ran this on my QA and production server and it went perfectly.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

But when I run it locally, the trace responds fine. I can tell it's accessing my database because of my `.scss.erb` file. And that *something happened*, but when I reboot my server, and inspect my css file, no changes were actually made.

**Additional notes :**

My application.rb has ->

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

---

The contents of colors.scss.erb

```
<% Color.for_header.each do |color| %>
#super_header.color-<%= color.id %>, #eheader.color-<%= color.id %> {
  background-color: #<%= color.code %>;
  background-image: none;
}
<% end %>

<% Color.for_highlight.each do |color| %>
.lists-list.color-<%= color.id %> li {
  &.current a {
    &:before { background: url(/images/group-select-end-left/<%= color.image %>) no-repeat !important; }
    &:after  { background: url(/images/group-select-end-right/<%= color.image %>) no-repeat !important;}    
  }
  &.active, &.current {
    a {
      background-color: #<%= color.code %> !important;
      background-image: none !important;
    }
    &:before {
      background: url(/images/group-select-end-left/<%= color.image %>) no-repeat !important;
      left: -9px;
      height: 39px;
      width: 9px;      
    }
    &:after {
      background: url(/images/group-select-end-right/<%= color.image %>) no-repeat;
      right: -10px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 30px;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
}
<% end %>
```

Comment: did you run the migrations on the production database?

Comment: As the environment uses the same `database.yml` settings, I guess a clear way to test DB connectivity will be to ask whether it works when you browse to the domain?

Comment: Sam D. - Yes I ran all the migrations. The same issue occurs on my localhost. QA is the only box that worked :D  // Rich Peck. - So I can definitely connect to the database otherwise in prod/qa/local through console, and the app is otherwise fully functional.

Comment: Can you share the result of `rake assets:precompile --trace` on production environment.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Cool, I added it up above. Thanks.. The only environment this *doesn't* work on is my local.

Comment: @Trip Can you share the contents of `colors.scss.erb`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat  Just updated, pasted above.

Comment: @Trip Hmm.. Looks alright. Could you share the database.yml entry for development environment.

Comment: @Trip Did you intend to use `sqlite` adapter or should it be `sqlite3`? You didn't share `database.yml` so I can't say for sure. But you can take a look at that.

Comment: ah thanks for the reply @KirtiThorat , my adaptor is sqlite3.

Comment: As per the error logs `rake` task is looking in `sqlite_adapter` instead of `sqlite3_adapter`.

Comment: Wow great eye! Strange though. Wouldn't the database.yml decide that?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Ah so it was most certainly because I wasn't instantiated a RAILS_ENV. But if I do that, it runs successfully, but nothing actually updates. Updated my answer above..

Answer (score 1):

Since `rake` loads all `Rails` stack, you probably need to add the environemnt:

```
RAILS_ENV=your_env_name bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It works on my staging server (no `heroku`) using `capistrano`.

Comment: Interesting. Well this runs through everything. And I see it get past the error, but it doesn't actually compile my css.